# Why copy command is not working when using file paths?

Tags: linux, shell, path, sh

I'm having a problem with the copy command.

`cp ../teste/env/test/x.tar ../../../teste2/file`

The folders exist and also the file x.tar. When I start the script I'm on a different folder, so that's why I make a `../` at the begining.

It keeps giving me this error: `cp: cannot create regular file ‘../../../teste2/file’: No such file or directory`

Worth to note that both teste and teste2 folders are on the same directory.

This is folder teste tree: [teste tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjXte.png)

This is folder test2 tree: [teste2 tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cyqc.png)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Did you check the permissions / ownership of the file and folder? Is the folder perhaps owned by another user or root and maybe the current user can't access / see it? Could you try `cp ../teste/env/test/x.tar ../../../teste2/.` or `cp ../teste/env/test/x.tar ../../../.` just to debug it.

Comment: I'm with sudo, and I've chmod them to both get write and read permissions. I'm very confused

Comment: Try running `ls -al ../../../teste2/`, in order to check if you might have miscalculated thenumber of `../` prefixes.

Comment: It's getting the correct output

Comment: If I run ```cd ../teste``` ```cd env/test``` then ```cp x.tar ../../../teste2/file``` it works fine;

Comment: Could you please add your file tree to the question?

Comment: Added the trees

Comment: It's important to see in which relation the trees are to each other. Check my answer. If it doesn't work, you should add the whole tree in which I can see in which relation the two trees are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments I tried to rebuild the file tree you might have. I think the following call might work. You just miscalculated the relative paths.

```
cp ../teste/env/test/x.tar ../teste2/file
```

The relative path is always calculated from the current working directory meaning the folder from which you call the command.